# Custom Class sort property with NSDate not working in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I create the custom class name with FileModel.

```
 FileModel.h

 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface FileModel : NSObject

 @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *fileName;
 @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString *fileType;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate   *editDate;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger fileSize;

 @end
```

I want to sort the FileModel with the editDate, but it is not work.

I create the sample  like below .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

         NSArray *fileSampleName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"apple.png",@"banana.png",@"cherry.png",@"durian.png",@"grape.png",@"avocado.png", nil];

         NSMutableArray *fileData = [NSMutableArray new];
         FileModel *fileModel = nil;
         for( NSInteger i = 0 ; i < fileSampleName.count  ; i++){
             fileModel = [FileModel new];
             fileModel.fileName = [fileSampleName objectAtIndex:i];
             fileModel.fileType = @"photo";
             fileModel.fileSize = 0;
             fileModel.editDate = [NSDate new];
             [fileData addObject:fileModel];
             // test for nsdate interveral
             [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

         }

         NSArray *sortedArray;
         sortedArray = [fileData      sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(FileModel *a, FileModel *b)      {
             NSDate *first = [(FileModel*)a editDate];
             NSDate *second =  [(FileModel*)a editDate];
             return [second compare:first];
         }];
         NSLog(@"sortedArray:%@",sortedArray);

         // log
         for (FileModel *fm in sortedArray) {
             NSLog(@"sortedArray:%@", fm.fileName);
         }
     }
```

Why I NSLog sorted order is not

> avocado.png -> grape.png -> durian.png -> cherry.png -> banana.png ->
>   apple.png

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss typed **a** again instead of **b** in second variable

```
  NSArray *sortedArray;
  sortedArray = [fileData   sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(FileModel *a, FileModel *b)      {
    NSDate *first = [(FileModel*)a editDate];
    NSDate *second =  [(FileModel*)b editDate];
    return [second compare: first];
   }];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
NSArray *sortArray = [fileData sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSDate *first = [(FileModal*)obj1 editDate];
    NSDate *second =  [(FileModal*)obj2 editDate];
    return !([first compare:second] == NSOrderedDescending);
}];
```